# UnsubscriptionError: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my angular 8 app I am subscribing to an observable which should merge with another observable for a given set of input observables completing in arrays.

The code looks like this:

```js
const obs1 = Observable.of([1,2,3]);
const obs2 = Observable.of([4,5,6]);
const obs3 = Observable.of([7,8,9]);

const obs = [obs1, obs2, obs3]; // obs1-3 are three observables
from(obs).pipe(
  mergeAll(),
  mergeMap(res => res.map(val => functionReturningAnObservable(val))),
  mergeAll(),
  finalize(() => someSideAction())
).subscribe();
```

The code works fine. However, my finalize call crashes due to a call stack size excession (the side action isn't especially lightweight). It happens when I increase the number of input observables or the number of values in the arrays.
In the stack trace I see that there are about 180 calls related to the above observable. How can I run the finalize call outside of the observables call stack?

Comment: You could move it to the third function passed to `.subscribe()`.  The `complete` function described [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObserverDoc.html).

Comment: This error normally indicates that your code is not so optimized. I'll suggest looking into refactoring instead.

Comment: @FanCheung I agree. I will look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call your function inside the subscribe method you can try

```
...subscribe({
  next: (data) => {/*data retrieval*/},
  error: (err) => {/*error callback*/},
  complete: ()=> {someSideAction()}})
```

this will execute after `next` callback is completed.

see [this article](https://appdividend.com/2017/04/25/observables-in-rxjs/#Output-5)

Comment: sure I will do that